# Maven não encontrando o java

Tags: java, maven

Estou tentando rodar o maven e está me retornando o seguinte erro:

```
/opt/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn: 227: exec: /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java: not found
```

Eu conferi os caminhos e estão ok, alguém sabe o porquê do problema?

Meu *environment* está assim:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:‌​/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/java/bin:/opt/maven/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/opt/java"
M2_HOME="/opt/maven"
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=200m"
MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=300m -Xms500m -Xmx1300m -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 -Dencoding=ISO-8859-1"
```

Comment: Tenta executar um `/opt/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn -version` e um `/opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java -version`, e posta aí o que ele escreve como resposta.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, quando executo o maven, me retorna o mesmo erro, já quando executo o java -version... aparece "-bash: /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado" estranho porque consigo ir manualmente lá e executar o java -version.

Comment: Você configurou o maven no seu path?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462247/how-to-setup-path-for-maven,
você tem algo parecido com isso? M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-2.2.1

M2=%M2_HOME%\bin

MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m

Comment: Sim, veja como está meu arquivo enviroment...PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/java/bin:/opt/maven/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/opt/java"
M2_HOME="/opt/maven"
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=200m"
MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=300m -Xms500m -Xmx1300m -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 -Dencoding=ISO-8859-1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu JAVA_HOME e seu M2_HOME estão errados. Os seus estão assim:

```
JAVA_HOME="/opt/java"
M2_HOME="/opt/maven"
```

Deveriam ser assim:

```
JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk1.7.0_79"
M2_HOME="/opt/apache-maven-3.3.3"
```

Seu PATH também está errado. O seu está assim:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:‌​/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/java/bin:/opt/maven/bin"
```

Deveria ser assim:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:‌​/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin"
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder, estava assim antes, eu acabei de alterar para ficar mais fácil de manusear.

Comment: Muito bom @VictorStafusa, haha foi mais rapido na resposta